# Excel: Sum [range] if cell equals value of another cell

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function, microsoft-excel-2010

```
  |   A   |    B  |
1 | Value | Input |
2 |  1000 |  1000 |
3 |  3000 |  3000 |
4 |  5000 |   150 |
5 | 10000 |       |
6 | 15000 |  3000 |
7 | 20000 | 20000 |
  -----------------
```

**I'd like to know if there's a formula (or combination of formulas) to sum Column B ONLY it equals Column A?**

On the table above, the total should be 24,000 because only B2, B3 and B7 have the same values as the cells on Column A

Answer (score 4):

You can use an array formula for this:

```
{=SUM(IF(B2:B7=A2:A7,B2:B7,0))}
```

Enter the formula `=SUM(IF(B2:B7=A2:A7,B2:B7,0))` (without the braces),
and press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Enter</kbd> to make it an array formula (and then the braces will appear).

...

**Or** you could also use `SUMPRODUCT` which does not require it to be entered as an array:

```
=SUMPRODUCT(--(B2:B7=A2:A7),B2:B7)
```

Comment: @Omar: What are you talking about?  The data in your question are in Columns ``A`` and `B` and go from row 2 to row 7, so `A2:A7` and `B2:B7` are correct.  (Unless you actually have “A” in `B1`, “B” in `C1`, “1” in `A2`, “Value” in `B2`, “Input” in `C2`, “2” in `A3`, “1000” in `B3` and `C3`, etc., which would be very odd.)

Comment: the array formula needs to be typed without the initial brackets, `=SUM(IF(A3:A8=B3:B8,B3:B8,0))` Once you press ctrl+shift+enter, Excel will automatically add them

Comment: @Omar: I have already edited the answer to explain about the braces and the Ctrl+Shift+Enter. Please explain why you say the formula should look at rows 3 through 8 (you even ***say*** in the text of the question that ``B2`` needs to be considered), and why you believe that ``A=B`` is not equivalent to ``B=A``.

Comment: @PeterH:  Why did you approve Omar’s suggested edit?  Your answer was perfectly fine; his changes are merely trivial style preferences that don’t affect the result.  (I advise you to reject/rollback that edit.)

Comment: @G-Man it is NOT a "style". The formula won't work, Need the corrections.

Comment: @Omar: Testing `A=B` is equivalent to testing `B=A`; changing the order is a trivial style preference. Excel is reasonably tolerant of operators and operands being strung together without spaces; changing `--` to `⁠ -- ⁠` (adding spaces) is a trivial style preference.  I agree that changing `A2:A7` and `B2:B7` to  ‭`B3:B8` and `C3:C8` is *not* a trivial style preference; it is an error, since your data are in `A2:A7` and `B2:B7`. … (Cont’d)

Comment: (Cont’d) …  If you disagree, please [edit your question](https://superuser.com/posts/1380357/edit) to show a screenshot of your data with PeterH’s formulas and your versions of them, demonstrating that and explaining how his ‘‘won't work’’ and ‘‘have errors’’ (as you keep claiming) and only yours produce correct results. And, if you can’t do that, you should reinstate your acceptance of this answer.